# Firebase Authentication Failed when try to logged In

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Firebase Authentication Failed. I have implemented Firebase authentication and try to navigate another screen after successfully validate.
I have an activity where user have to provide their email and password to create an account but whenever I am giving my email and password its giving a toast message "Authentication failed". Here is my code

```
1. package com.example.videoapp

        import android.R.attr
        import android.app.ProgressDialog
        import android.content.Intent
        import android.os.Bundle
        import android.text.TextUtils
        import android.widget.EditText
        import android.widget.ProgressBar
        import android.widget.Toast
        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
        import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
        import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
        import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
        import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
        import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_create_acc.*
        import java.util.jar.Attributes


        @Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")
        class create_acc : AppCompatActivity() {
            lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
            lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference
            lateinit var mProgressBar: ProgressDialog

            override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_acc)
                mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                val mRegUsername = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username)
                val mRegEmail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.email)
                val mRegPassword=findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password)
                mProgressBar= ProgressDialog(this)

                creates.setOnClickListener {
                    val name = mRegUsername.text.toString().trim()
                    val password = mRegPassword.text.toString().trim()
                    val email = mRegEmail.text.toString().trim()

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
                        mRegUsername.error = "Enter name"
                        return@setOnClickListener
                    }
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                        mRegEmail.error = "Enter email"
                        return@setOnClickListener
                    }
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                        mRegPassword.error = "Enter password"
                        return@setOnClickListener
                    }


                    createUser(name,email,password)
                }



            }

    private fun createUser(name: String, email: String, password: String) {
                mProgressBar.setMessage("Please wait.....")
                mProgressBar.show()
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(
                        this
                    ) { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
                            val uid = currentUser!!.uid

                            val userMap = HashMap<String,String>()
                            userMap["Name"]= name
                            mDatabase.child(uid).setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener { task
    ->
                                if (task.isSuccessful){
                                    val intent = Intent(applicationContext,account_setting::class.java)
                                    startActivity(intent)
                                    finish()
                                    Toast.makeText(this,"Account created                 successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                                    mProgressBar.dismiss()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {

                            Toast.makeText(this,"Authentication 
                            failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            mProgressBar.dismiss()

                        }
                    }
            }
    }
```

what shall I do so that my code can run

Comment: For starters, check the exception that's attached to the task in the onComplete callback.

Comment: Have you tried to use `Log.d("TAG", task.exception.message!!)` to see if something is printed out in the logcat?

Comment: No its not working , its giving an error "Unsolved reference"